# Hide Axis Titles in Seaborn

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

Given the following heatmap, how would I remove the axis titles ('month' and 'year')?

```py
import seaborn as sns

# Load the example flights dataset and conver to long-form
flights_long = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights_long.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")

# Draw a heatmap with the numeric values in each cell
sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True, fmt="d", linewidths=.5)
```

[image: current graph]

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Before calling `sns.heatmap`, get the axes using `plt.subplots`, then use `set_xlabel` and `set_ylabel`. For example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load the example flights dataset and conver to long-form
flights_long = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights_long.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")

# ADDED: Extract axes.
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (15, 15), dpi=300)

# Draw a heatmap with the numeric values in each cell
sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True, fmt="d", linewidths=.5)

# ADDED: Remove labels.
ax.set_ylabel('')    
ax.set_xlabel('')
```

[image: New graph]

Answer (score 4):

The axis labels come from axis names from the dataframe; so another way to do this job is to remove the axis names from the source dataframe by calling `rename_axis()` on it.

```py
import seaborn as sns
flights_long = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights_long.pivot(index="month", columns="year", values="passengers")

sns.heatmap(flights.rename_axis(index=None, columns=None), annot=True, fmt="d", cmap='RdBu');
#                   ^^^^^^^^^^^ remove axis names here
```

---

Also, `heatmap()` returns an Axes object, on which `set()` can be called to "remove" the axis labels.

```py
ax = sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True, fmt="d", cmap='RdBu')
ax.set(ylabel='', xlabel='');
```

or even as a one-liner:

```py
sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True, fmt="d", cmap='RdBu').set(xlabel='', ylabel='');
```

[image: image result]