# Remove axis titles from Seaborn PairGrid

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I've tried using the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34275363/1840471) to [Hide Axis Titles in Seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34275140/1840471), which applies to `heatmap`, but end up with two plots instead: the first being an empty grid without axis titles, the second being the `PairGrid` but still with axis titles. How can I hide the axis titles on the `PairGrid`?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (10, 10), dpi=300)
sns.PairGrid(iris).map_diag(sns.distplot)
ax.set_ylabel('')    
ax.set_xlabel('')
```

[image: plot 1 - empty grid with no labels]

[image: plot 2 - normal plot with labels]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop through the subplots and clear the titles for each of them.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

g = sns.PairGrid(iris).map_diag(sns.distplot)
for ax in g.axes.flatten():
    ax.set_ylabel('')
    ax.set_xlabel('')
```

[image: plot result]